# Is there a way to access a variable in .py file from Anaconda prompt?

Tags: python, anaconda

Is there a way to access variable in python file from Anaconda Prompt?
Here is a simple example of what I have saved as "example.py"

```
for i in range(10):
   if i%2==0:
       a=i
```

I can simply run the code and get the value of a, however I was wondering if there is a way that I can access the value of a in Anaconda Prompt. (i.e: print the value of a in Anaconda Prompt after running the code).

I understand that I can put the print('a=',a) in my code to get the value of a printed after running "example.py", but I am curious if I can do this through Anaconda Prompt.

Comment: import the module?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you meant by "import the module".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no you can't. Anaconda Prompt (like any other prompt) runs programs. This means it asks the OS for RAM space, opens a program, runs commands, and then closes that space when the program says so (in python, programs that reach the last line automatically close, unlike other languages where you have to specify your exit code). When you wrote your last line of code in your example.py you told the OS to kill the program at that point.

You can wrap your program in another python program and attempt to do stuff there instead. For example,

```
>> python -c "import os; print(os.getlogin())"
```

Hence, if your variable was some how accessible in your python code you could,

```
>> python -c "from example import a; print(a)"
```